How to run a sensitivity power analysis for linear mixed modeling (lme4 and simr)?
We conducted a behavior change field experiment using the following variables:

Two time points (T0, T1)
Two groups (intervention vs. control)
Individual ID (n = 62 in group 1, n = 53 in group 2)
Workshop ID (8 workshops)

We are analyzing the data in lme4 using this model
lmer(DV_T1 ~ 1 + group + DV_T0 + (1|workshop_id), data=df)

Sample size was given by resource constraints which is why we decided to run a sensitivity power analysis to detect the minimum effect size of interest (https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/08-samplesizejustification.html).
We tried doing this using the simr package, but we am not entirely sure whether our approach is appropriate (it throws NAs/0s)? Many thanks for any hints/advice/resources.
library(lme4)
library(simr)

n1 <- 62  
n2 <- 53  
n_total <- n1 + n2  
n_workshops <- 8 

simulate_data <- function(effect_size, n_total, n_workshops, n1, n2) {
  workshop_ID <- factor(rep(1:n_workshops, length.out = n_total))
  group <- factor(rep(c("Group1", "Group2"), times = c(n1, n2)))
  DV_T0 <- rnorm(n_total)
  DV_T1 <- DV_T0 + effect_size * (group == "Group2") + rnorm(n_total, 0, 1) 
  
  data.frame(DV_T1 = DV_T1,
             DV_T0 = DV_T0,
             group = group,
             workshop_ID = workshop_ID)
}

effect_sizes <- seq(0.1, 1.0, by = 0.1)

power_analysis <- function(effect_size) {
  simulated_data <- simulate_data(effect_size, n_total, n_workshops, n1, n2)
  
  model <- lmer(DV_T1 ~ DV_T0 + group + (1 | workshop_ID), data = simulated_data)
  
  if (isSingular(model)) {
    return(NA)
  }
  
  power_simulation <- powerSim(model, nsim = 1000, test = fixed("groupGroup2"))
  
  return(summary(power_simulation)$mean)  
 value
}

powers <- sapply(effect_sizes, power_analysis)

valid_indices <- !is.na(powers)
plot(effect_sizes[valid_indices], powers[valid_indices], type = "b", xlab = "Effect Size", ylab = "Power",
     main = "Sensitivity Analysis")
abline(h = 0.80, col = "red", lty = 2)  
power


Using your collected data would be equivalent to doing a post hoc power analysis. I would simulate

Thank you! We tried doing that, but have not managed to get the code to work yet (see above). Do you know any resourced by any chance? Many thanks :)
